# Query to get categorised sets of splits

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS splits (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sector_id INT,
    type VARCHAR(100),
    percentage INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX (type)
) ENGINE MyISAM;
```

And this data set:

```
INSERT INTO splits (sector_id, type, percentage) VALUES
(1, 'Manager', '50'),
(1, 'Sales Rep', '50'),
(2, 'Manager', '75'),
(2, 'Sales Rep', '25'),
(3, 'Manager', '75'),
(3, 'Sales Rep', '25'),
(4, 'Manager', '100'),
(5, 'Manager', '100'),
(6, 'Manager', '100');
```

How could I return the amount of sectors that split in the same way:

Like this:

```
Split          | Number
---------------+-------
50% M / 50% SR | 1
75% M / 25% SR | 2
100% M         | 3
```

So this shows 1 sector (id 1) has a split ratio of 50/50, 2 sectors have a split ratio of 75/25 (ids 2, 3) and 3 sectors have a split ratio off 100/0 (ids 4, 5, 6).

Here is a SQL Fiddle with the database setup: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b19f/1

> *What have you tried?*

I cannot even think of where to start to solve this problem, so I apologise for not being able to show an attempted solution. I will update this question if I get anywhere.

The reason why I want to do this all in the database (and not the application) is because our automated reporting tools can be pointed to a table/view/query and automatically apply filtering, sorting, charting etc. To do it manually in the application loses all the default functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the problem. Your DB contains already all the data you want to retrieve?!

```
SELECT
  sector_id AS Number,
  type
  percentage
FROM
  splits
```

The easiest thing would now to take you software and then turn those (type-percentage)-tuples into strings. **Why do you need the database to create and concat this string?**

**Can there be more than 2 `type`s?**

For Postgres I'd use an array of tuples for output:

```
SELECT
  sector_id,
  array_agg(row(percentage, type))
FROM
  splits
GROUP BY
  sector_id
```

---

## Correct Query:

```
SELECT
  x.y,
  COUNT(*) c
FROM (
  SELECT
    sector_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(percentage, '% '), type SEPARATOR ' / ') AS y
  FROM (
    SELECT
      sector_id,
      type,
      percentage
    FROM splits
    ORDER BY sector_id, type
  ) z
  GROUP BY sector_id
) x
GROUP BY x.y
ORDER by c
```

Result will look like this:

```
50% Manager / 50% Sales Rep | 1
75% Manager / 25% Sales Rep | 2
100% Manager                | 3
```

Comment: `Number` is not the `sector_id`, it is the amount of unique `sector_ids` that have the same split ratio. I.e. there is 3 sectors that split 100% to the manager. As for "why", our automated report tools can be pointed to a table/view/query and automatically apply filtering, sorting, charting etc. To do it manually in the application loses all the default functionality.

Comment: Okay, then another attempt. So you want: the sum of all unique sector_ids where the percentage ratio is equal?

Comment: Yes (if by that you mean the count rather than sum).

Comment: Oh, and "Can there be more than 2 types?" ideally yes. But I can live with only 2 if needs be.

Comment: 2 types could get hard-coded, but you know that this is ugly ;) I'll try to figure out a query, or maybe someone else here is faster. ... It's somehow damn tricky ;)

Comment: I'VE GOT IT (95%). Will post the query at the bottom of my answer. It's not that nice, but working.

Comment: there's a comma (and no whitespace) separating the entries.

Comment: That's totally fine, the formatting is not a big deal I can do that on the application side.

Comment: Ah, I've got a 'custom' separator. i'll append the query. Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b19f/29/0

Comment: Sorry, there's a little problem with the query... I'll correct the last one in my answer. Here's the new version (look at the initial ordering of manager and sales rep): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7ca7/5/0